# Amazon subscription is not working on first time in Unity. and works on 2nd time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, amazon-appstore

I'm working in Unity Game for amazon app store. the subscription purchase is getting successful but the purchaseresult function is not calling on first time and it does not give a reward. when we just click to buy again and remind them. it says you have already subscribe. then at that time the reward function is getting called and give the reward.

i have tried the Unity iap simple script and also codeless iap in Unity.